# Sanity check - monotone increasing function on $[0,\infty)$ and integral of its derivative

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be monotone-increasing. Then, it is well-known that the derivative $f'$ exists and takes nonnegative values almost everywhere on $[0,\infty)$.

Then, is it true that
\begin{equation}
f(b) - f(a) \geq \int_a^b f'(t) dt \text{ for "all" } 0 \leq a < b <\infty
\end{equation}
holds?

In Folland Real Analysis p. 108, exercise 33, he states the same result for $\mathbb{R}$ rather than $[0,\infty)$. I strongly suspect that the statement holds valid on $[0,\infty)$ without any change, but would like to make sure that I am correct.

Could anyone please clarify for me?

Comment: When you say monotone increasing do you mean strict inequality? Otherwise you can just extend $f$ to $(-\infty,0)$ to be constant $f(0)$ there.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur I do not mean strict inequality. Well...yes you are correct. I was dumb.

Comment: This is just a statement about functions $f: [a, b] \to \Bbb R$.

Comment: If the statement holds true for all $\Bbb R$, and $A$ is any interval in $\Bbb R$, then it very obviously would also hold true for that interval: If $a, b \in A$ with $a\le b$, then $a,b \in \Bbb R$, so by the statement on $\Bbb R, f(b) - f(a) \ge \int_a^b f'(t)\,dt$. Q.E.D. As $[0,\infty)$ is an interval, that settles your question. The proof that it holds on $\Bbb R$ itself is not quite so trivial.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes, the case of $\mathbb{R}$ is the exercise in Folland book.

Comment: I was a little too cavalier in that previous comment. After all, maybe $f: A \to \Bbb R$ cannot be extended to a function with the same properties on all of $\Bbb R$, for instance $A = (0,\infty)$ and $f(x) = \ln x$ cannot be extended to a larger domain and still be increasing. Since your interval is closed, any $f$ on it can always be extended. More generally, the result I claimed is still true, but minor adjustments to the proof are necessary.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I agree. But with $A=[0,\infty)$, the first comment is the easiest way to get the desired result.